# Action listener in an array of Jbuttons placed in 5 differnt JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I had an assignment to place the letter of the alphabet in 5 panels with the layout that I coded below.  When you select a button it changes the `JLabel` to read the button that was clicked.
The first way I did it, I wrote everything out by adding each button separately to each panel and adding all the `ActionListeners` and text.  It was about 200 line but worked fine.  I thought it would be more concise to put the `JButtons` into arrays and add the listeners and text at this point.  I was able to get the `JFrame` to layout, but I have no idea how to use the `ActionListener`.  Do I have to add a `MouseListener` to find out what panel was clicked and then determine the button was pressed?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JFileCabinet1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    String[] lettersPanel1 = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
    String[] lettersPanel2 = { "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L" };
    String[] lettersPanel3 = { "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R" };
    String[] lettersPanel4 = { "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X" };
    String[] lettersPanel5 = { "Y", "Z" };

    private JPanel jp1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 6));
    private JPanel jp2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 6));
    private JPanel jp3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 6));
    private JPanel jp4 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 6));
    private JPanel jp5 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 6));

    private JButton jblank1 = new JButton();
    private JButton jblank2 = new JButton();
    private JButton jblank3 = new JButton();
    private JLabel jl = new JLabel("");

    private Container con = getContentPane();
    private GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(5, 1, 5, 5);

    public JFileCabinet1() {

        super("File cabinet");

        con.add(jp1);
        for (int i = 0; i < lettersPanel1.length; i++) {
            JButton button[] = new JButton[lettersPanel1.length];
            button[i] = new JButton(lettersPanel1[i]);
            jp1.add(button[i]);
            button[i].addActionListener(this);
        }

        con.add(jp2);
        for (int i = 0; i < lettersPanel2.length; i++) {
            JButton button[] = new JButton[lettersPanel2.length];
            button[i] = new JButton(lettersPanel2[i]);
            jp2.add(button[i]);
            button[i].addActionListener(this);
        }

        con.add(jp3);
        for (int i = 0; i < lettersPanel2.length; i++) {
            JButton button[] = new JButton[lettersPanel3.length];
            button[i] = new JButton(lettersPanel3[i]);
            jp3.add(button[i]);
            button[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
        con.add(jp4);
        for (int i = 0; i < lettersPanel4.length; i++) {
            JButton button[] = new JButton[lettersPanel4.length];
            button[i] = new JButton(lettersPanel4[i]);
            jp4.add(button[i]);
            button[i].addActionListener(this);
        }

        con.add(jp5);
        for (int i = 0; i < lettersPanel5.length; i++) {
            JButton button[] = new JButton[lettersPanel5.length];
            button[i] = new JButton(lettersPanel2[i]);
            jp5.add(button[i]);
            button[i].addActionListener(this);
        }

        jp5.add(jblank1).setVisible(false);
        jp5.add(jblank2).setVisible(false);
        jp5.add(jblank3).setVisible(false);

        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(layout);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton src = (JButton) e.getSource();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileCabinet1 frame = new JFileCabinet1();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: your actionPerformed does not do anything expect finding a specific  button that is clicked

Comment: I know, the ActionPreformed is not finished.  The question I have is when the button is pressed does the information of which array and the location of the jbutton get communicated?  I will need to change the the jlabel to match the button letter designation.

Comment: when I use getSource, I keep getting null. Nevertheless, when I use getActionCommand, I can write any JButton when it is clicked. I feel your approach is wrong, but I do not know how to explain so I will wait for other to explain so I can learn too.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to add a mouse listener to find out what panel was clicked
>   and then determine the button was pressed?

No, don't use mouse listeners on buttons. Your `ActionListener` implementation is fine and `getSource` will give you the button which was pressed.

To set the label to the text of the button, use `jl.setText(src.getText())` inside `actionPerformed`.

If you want the panel which the button is in, use `getParent()` of the button.

Answer (score 2):

The reality is, you don't actually need the arrays, directly any way, for the `ActionListener`, once `actionPerformed` is fired, you can get the `JButton` from the `ActionEvent`s source property and extract the text from the button...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton src = (JButton) e.getSource();
    System.out.println(src.getText());
}
```

Now, if you want the button to carry more information (or different information then what is displayed) you can use the buttons `actionCommand` property.

Also, this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < lettersPanel2.length; i++) {
    JButton button[] = new JButton[lettersPanel2.length];
```

Doesn't make sense.  Every time the loop runs, it is creating a new `JButton` array and it's only creating a local button array within the context of the `for-loop`

If you look at your `for-loop`s, they are generally doing the same thing, the only difference is the source content (the character arrays) and where you're adding the buttons.  You write a method to do this, for example...

```
public void addButtonsTo(String[]  letters, JPanel panel)  {
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        JButton button = new JButton(letters[i]);
        panel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }
}
```

And simply call it like...

```
addButtonsTo(lettersPanel1, jp1);
addButtonsTo(lettersPanel2, jp2);
addButtonsTo(lettersPanel3, jp3);
addButtonsTo(lettersPanel4, jp4);
addButtonsTo(lettersPanel5, jp5);
```

Have a read through [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details...